# POST em Web API retorna Content Type Inválido

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, post

Estou tentando enviar uma requisição POST para uma Web API.

Se eu faço pelo Postman, funciona:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora quando tento realizar através do código, obtenho o seguinte erro:

```
{
    "status": false,
    "message": "Content Type Inválido. (Formato aceito: Content Type = \"application/json\" ",
    "total": 0
}
```

Já tentei dessa maneira:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Constants.APIV2);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "application/json");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Constants.APIAuth)));

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(billing);

HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, Constants.Billing);
request.Content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

await client.SendAsync(request)
    .ContinueWith(responseTask =>
    {
        var teste = responseTask.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    });
```

E dessa:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Constants.APIV2);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Constants.APIAuth)));

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(billing);

HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(Constants.Billing, new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));

if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

E sem sucesso.

Alguma ideia do que eu poderia estar fazendo de errado?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

apenas uma dica, mantenha em memoria a instancia do seu `HttpClient`, no seu `PostAsync` você deve informar apenas o caminho relativo. Entenda o motivo lendo o seguinte artigo: [`YOU'RE USING HTTPCLIENT WRONG AND IT IS DESTABILIZING YOUR SOFTWARE`](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/)

No mais, o seu codigo me parece correto, normalmente eu faço da seguinte forma

```
public class WebApiProxy
{
    private static HttpClient Client;

    static Base()
    {
        // var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        // var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
        // httpClientHandler.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
        // Client = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);

        Client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Constants.BaseUrl);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Constants.APIAuth)));
    }

    public async Task<Resposta> SendBilling(Billing billing)
    {
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(billing);
        var httpRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, Constants.RelativePath);
        httpRequest.Content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        using (var request = await Client.SendAsync(httpRequest))
        {
            if (request.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var responseJson = await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var responseWrap = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Resposta>(responseJson);
                return responseWrap;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Conversando com o AP através do Chat, identificamos que o problema era a validação mal feita realizada pela API.

O HttpClient envia junto ao `Content-Type` o `CHARSET`, tal comportamento inclusive está na especificação do protocolo.: [`W3C`](https://www.w3.org/International/articles/http-charset/index)

Porém a API não se comportava da forma esperada ao receber um `Content-Type` com `CHARSET`, ignorando assim a requisição.

Como solução de contorno, foi necessário remover o `charset` do `Content-Type`.:

```
var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"); 
content.Headers.ContentType.CharSet = string.Empty;
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela dica! Porém o meu post continua gerando o mesmo erro. O seu código está praticamente igual ao meu primeiro exemplo, a diferença é que o HttClient você cria em outro local.

Comment: @perozzo a API é de terceiros ou de sua autoria?

Comment: É de terceiros. É uma API de integração que estão implantando aqui na empresa. O estranho é que via Postman funciona perfeitamente...

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75001/perozzo-c-httpclient